# xmlhttp Request with callback function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to return the responsetext of an ajax call. I'm not succeeding and I get the whole time undefined:

```
function ajaxFunction(callback,tekstvar){
    xmlhttp= new GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp==null)
    {
          alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
          return;
    }
    var url="php/functions_translate.php";
    url=url+"?tekst="+tekstvar;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ 
            return callback(xmlhttp.responseText)
        };  
    }; 

    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function translate(tekstvar) {
  var text = ajaxFunction(function(tekst){return tekst;},tekstvar);
  return text;
}
```

I'm calling the translate function to give me a certain translation of word. Does anyone know, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? and are you debugging using `console.log()` ?

Comment: `callback` supposed to be a function

Comment: asynchronous calls can not return stuff!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined return value from the function call Javascritpt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460556/undefined-return-value-from-the-function-call-javascritpt)

Answer (score 0):

I've voted to close this due to duplicate. This answer is merely to make the answer found in the duplicate question more relevant to this specific question.

Please read this for more info: [Undefined return value from the function call Javascritpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460556/undefined-return-value-from-the-function-call-javascritpt/17460802#17460802)

---

You need to add a callback to the `translate()` function:

```
function translate(tekstvar,callback) {
  ajaxFunction(callback,tekstvar);
}
```

If you expect to call `translate` like this:

```
var newtext = translate(text);
displayText(newtext);
doSomethingElseWith(newtext);
```

then I'm sorry but that's not possible with asynchronous code. You need to put all the code that you would have written after calling the `translate` function to be inside the callback you pass into the translate function.

In other words, modify it like this:

```
var newtext = translate(text);
//
//--------------------------------------- move everything below this line
//                                        into the callback
displayText(newtext);
doSomethingElseWith(newtext);
```

so that it looks like this:

```
translate(text,function(newtext){
  displayText(newtext);
  doSomethingElseWith(newtext);
});
```