# Node.js - Asynchronous JSON Query

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I am new to Javascript and Node.js really hurts my head because it is asynchronous.

My goal is to query for a JSON object from an API and be able to work with it. I have tried to look for questions and answers on what I should be doing but none of it really makes sense to me, so I am hoping to learn by just seeing proper code.

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'url here';
var temp;
var done = false;

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
      temp = body;
      done = true;
      console.log(temp);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

if (done){
  console.log(temp);
```

}

Can someone please walk me through the proper way to restructure my code?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460556/undefined-return-value-from-the-function-call-javascritpt/17460802#17460802 . Especially the part at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: A variant of this question is asked many times per day.  The root of this issue is that you need to really understand what an asynchronous response is and how to use it.  The first thing to understand is that your asynchronous callback is called some time LATER, yet the lines of code right after your function run immediately BEFORE the asynchronous response has run.  Thus, you can ONLY use the asynchronous response inside the callback.  Put all code that needs to use the response inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are creating with the line

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
```

is not executed until the response is received.  The rest of your code continues to run.  Think of the flow something like this:

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'url here';
var temp;
var done = false;

request(url, XXX);

if (done){
  console.log(temp);
```

then when the response is received (perhaps much later on) the function `XXX` is executed.

As you can see, `done` will always be false when the line

```
if (done){
```

is executed.

Comment: I see that, when I run it in Terminal it stalls and eventually gives me an error. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you want to do anything with the response, you have to do it INSIDE function `XXX`.  This makes your `done` variable redundant.

Comment: Inside that function `XXX` I'd suggest you put the line `debugger;` at the top and play around in the console.  In particular, inspect the `error`, `response` and `body` objects to familiarise yourself with what they hold.

Comment: Is there a way to save the response to an object and work with the object afterwords?

Comment: Try not to think like that... the "afterwards" is IN that function.  Try watching some youtube clips on Javascript and asynchronous functional programming - its really quite beautiful.