# How to make the function syncronous

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the code as below, which prints the largest partyCode:

Working:

```
var partyWithLargestPartyCode = Party.find().sort("-partyCode").limit(1); 
var largestPartyCode;
partyWithLargestPartyCode.exec(function(err, p) {
    largestPartyCode = p[0].partyCode;
    console.log(largestPartyCode);    
});
```

Output:

```
3
```

Not Working:

```
var partyWithLargestPartyCode = Party.find().sort("-partyCode").limit(1); 
var largestPartyCode;
partyWithLargestPartyCode.exec(function(err, p) {
    largestPartyCode = p[0].partyCode;
});

console.log(largestPartyCode);
```

output:

```
undefined
```

So, I would like to make the second code block to work. How can I do that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: You cannot output `largePartyCode` before it is being found / calculated.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I know that, So, I want to make the function syncronous.

Comment: @Vishal `exec` is an asynchronous method, you cannot call it synchronously. It is a common practice for JavaScript and Node.JS. Why would you want to call it synchronously?

Comment: Because I want to save a new party and I want its partyCode to be automatically calculated based on the largest partyCode.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460556/undefined-return-value-from-the-function-call-javascritpt/17460802#17460802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the second example work, because this is how asynchrony works. It takes some time for `partyWithLargestPartyCode.exec()` to process and will always execute later than `console.log(largestPartyCode);`.

If you want to learn more about it, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

In the future you will be able to write asynchronous code in a synchronous manner with `async/await` that will look something like this:

```
async function myFunc() {
    var myVar = await asynchFunction();
    console.log(myVar); // this will work
}
```

Comment: Then how can I do that?

Comment: I mean is there any other way that I get the value of largestPartyCode after function execution?

Comment: Only inside it's callback, like in the first example.